# Using SQL "Not In" in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists. I am trying to write a LINQ query.

My lists: Products, Dealers.

```
var productList=_context.ProductList
.Where(x=> x.Date=>new DateTime(2021,02,01)       ).ToList();
```

I want to add the T-SQL constraint (below) to my LINQ, I tried with `foreach` but I can not handle it.

```
DealerCode Not IN(Select DealerCode from Dealers D With (nolock) Where D.ProductId=P.ProductId)
```

I don't want to do like `!x.DealerCode.Contains(.....)`, because my lists are so big and I will use this constraint in 8 different queries. I am searching How can I do that in a more efficient way.

Edit after comments:

T-SQL Query

```
Select * From ProductList P 
Where Date='2021-02-01' 
AND DealerCode Not IN(Select DealerCode from Dealers D With (nolock) Where D.ProductId=P.ProductId)
```

I am trying to write the query in LINQ

Comment: `foreach` isn't part of LINQ. It's used to process the results of a LINQ query

Comment: `With (nolock)` is a clear bug by the way. It means `take excessive locks while reading dirty and duplicate data, while randomly throwing exceptions`. If you have performance issues you need to fix them. If you have to use `NOLOCK` with an FK column like `ProductID` it means you're missing an index in one or both tables

Comment: Sorry but a "not in" have to be a "! ...Contains(...)"

Comment: @Arcord The constraint which I will add the query contains a query. Just an opinion: I create this list as a method outside of LINQ. Then can I call it in LINQ as `! X.DealerCode.Contains (somemethod (x.ProductID))` ?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz How? I am new in LINQ. If I join to tables, how can I say "not in "

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I add the SQL query in question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
var query = _context.ProductList
     .Where(a => a.Date != (_context.ProductList
     .Join(_context.Dealers,
     right => right.ProductId,
     left => left.ProductId,
     (right, left) => new
     {
         right = right,
         left = left
     })
     .Where(x => x.left.Date == a.Date)
     .Select(y => y.left.Date)).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate Navigation Properties to your models.  Products should have a navigation property called "Dealers" and Dealers should have a navigation property called "Products".  Once that is complete, your query becomes:

```
var query = _context.ProductList
  .Where(p => p.Date = new DateTime(2021,02,01))
  .Where(p => !p.Dealers.Any());
```

Assuming of course you are looking for products that have no dealers for it yet.  Or something similar.  Hard to tell without the complete models for ProductList, Dealers, etc.